# Brand New WD Black SMART DATA?

Tags: hard-drive

What is WD Black S.M.A.R.T  Vendor specific data 16?

I have a brand new WD Black 2TB and the 16. SMART value is decreasing from 300.000.000 to 190.000.000
Hard disk sentinel says vendor-specific data

And this value is OK?

Full smart

```
1    Raw Read Error Rate      51     200    200    0
3    Spin Up Time             21     100    253    0
4    Start/Stop Count         0      100    100    4
5    Reallocated Sectors Co.. 140    200    200    0
7    Seek Error Rate          0      200    200    0
9    Power On Time Count      0      100    100    96
10   Spin Retry Count         0      100    253    0
11   Drive Calibration Retr.. 0      100    253    0
12   Drive Power Cycle Count  0      100    100    3
16   Vendor-specific          0      0      200    190038634
192  Power off Retract Cycl.. 0      200    200    1
193  Load/Unload Cycle Count  0      200    200    2
194  Disk Temperature         0      117    115    33
196  Reallocation Event Count 0      200    200    0
197  Current Pending Sector.. 0      200    200    0
198  Off-Line Uncorrectable.. 0      100    253    0
200  Write Error Rate         0      100    253    0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full SMART test output.

Comment: Run the [WD Data Lifeguard diagnostics on the drive](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Western Digital [did not document](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1087/~/s.m.a.r.t.-attributes-supported-by-wd-eide-and-serial-ata-hard-drives) this attribute, its meaning is simply unknown. Your drive is fine otherwise, there’s nothing to worry about.